# How to write test scenarios and test cases for manual testing?

Tags: manual-testing

I am new at this, so please can you tell me how to learn to write test scenarios for web and mobile MANUAL testing?

Comment: Have you searched about these topics over web? I suggest you should first do some self-learning about these topics and if face some issue about  these topics then ask your question here.

Comment: A simple Google search would yield tons of results on this. Please go ahead and use the power.

Answer (score 1):

To start with manual testing u should thoroughly understand customer requirement. Scenarios are nothing but high level customer business work flows. From one requirement you can derive many scenarios and they may be negative scenario or positive scenario. For example requirement says username text field should accept 10 characters.You derive scenario like username text field should not accept more than 10 characters(-ve) and username text field shlould accept 10 or within 10 characters (+ve)